# jquery show() elements related to list items - not showing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I adapted that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Cxx2/ posted in an earlier thread in order to do basically the same thing: show one of four slideshows when clicking on one of four list items. Here's my new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7TkxG/
Nothing is showwing up, each slideshow div keeps its "display: none" and I can't get to know why. Anyone? thanks very much in advance!

```
<pre><code>
    <ul>
    <li>Choice:
        <br />
        <ul class="ssmenu">
            <li class="ssmenuitem"> <a href="#slideshowpro1">Project 1</a></li>
            <li class="ssmenuitem"> <a href="#slideshowpro2">Project 2</a></li>
            <li class="ssmenuitem"> <a href="#slideshowpro3">Project 3</a></li>
            <li class="ssmenuitem"> <a href="#slideshowpro4">Project 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshowpro1">slideshow1</div>
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshowpro2">slideshow2</div>
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshowpro3">slideshow3</div>
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshowpro3">slideshow4</div>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: where is the JS in this post?

Comment: Your fiddle is for MooTools, not jquery...  console reports `$(document).ready()` does not exist.  Might be a good place to start.

Comment: I just changed the fiddle to jquery, and it worked as-is.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MTzcT/4/)

```
$($( this).find('a').attr('href')).show();
```

you need to find `a` tag for getting `href` attribute

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MTzcT/5/)

```
$($('a',this).attr('href')).show();
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MTzcT/6/)

```
$($( this).children('a').attr('href')).show();
```

---

References

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
$($(this).attr('href')).show();
```

to:

```
$($(this).find('a').attr('href')).show();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MTzcT/3/)**

You're binding the click event to the list item, but you want to use the href attribute of the a element which is a child of that element, and hence you need to add `.find('a')`.

Comment: oh thank you so much! one more question though: why did the first fiddle work (the one I took as an example) without the "find()"?

Comment: Because in that example the click event is bound to the link `$(".menuitem")` which is an anchor element (`<a>`) where in your second example it's bound to the list item element `$(".ssmenuitem")` `<li>`.